# WebStorm array includes missing method error

Tags: webstorm, ecmascript-2016

WebStorm complains that `.includes` is an unresolved function.

I can only set it to use ES6 in the settings. There is no option for ES7.

How can I tell WebStorm to ignore this?

Comment: did you resolve this issue?

Comment: I'm having this bug in PHPStorm 2019.3

Answer (score 1):

What Webstorm version do you use? *Array.prototype.includes()* is correctly resolved in 2018.1.4 if **JavaScript language version** is set to **ECMAScript 6**:

[image]

Comment: Ugh... even though it's not part of ES6? Weird.

Comment: *ECMAScript 6* language level in WebStorm means ES6+

Comment: the problem exists in webstorm 2018.3

Comment: I have this in WebStorm 2022.3 _(#WS-223.7571.168)_: `console.log( [1,2,3].includes(1) );` --> `Unresolved function or method includes()`. Probably since the last update ? Was no problem some days ago.

Comment: works fine for me; please try invalidating the caches

Comment: invalidating cache didn't help 
#WS-222.4345.14, built on October 5, 2022